# Refactoring a switched block statement for group_by in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I rewrite this code so it's completely dynamic, and I don't have to use the `case` clause to manually list all possible values of `@group`?

```
# Grouping
@group = params[:group] if !params[:group].blank?
case @group
  when 'category_id'
    @ideas_grouped = @ideas.group_by { |i| i.category_id }
  when 'status_id'
    @ideas_grouped = @ideas.group_by { |i| i.status_id }
  when 'personal_bias'
    @ideas_grouped = @ideas.group_by { |i| i.personal_bias }
  when 'business_value'
    @ideas_grouped = @ideas.group_by { |i| i.business_value }
end
```

Comment: what's the expected resut if the param is blank? `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need no white-listing:

```
@ideas_grouped = if (group = params[:group]).present?
  @ideas.group_by(&group.to_sym)
end
```

If you need white-listing you may call `include?` first (see Amar's answer), but to add something new, let me push it with a declarative approach (`Object#whitelist` is left as an exercise for the reader, `maybe` comes from [Ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/)):

```
@ideas_grouped = params[:group].whitelist(IdeaGroupers).maybe do |group|
  @ideas.group_by(&group.to_sym)
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Just pure awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use some sort of meta programming
Above code can be refactored in one of the way is

```
if params[:group].present? && ["category_id","status_id","personal_bias","business_value"].include?(params[:group])
    @ideas_grouped = @ideas.group_by { |i| i.send(params[:group]) }
end
```

Comment: Yes but you're still listing the variables `"category_id","status_id","personal_bias","business_value"` - I want this to be completely dynamic.

Comment: if u don't want to validate then you can remove

Comment: If this is a named route you could create a constrain that can validate the parameter `match 'my_path/:group' => 'controller#action', constraints: {group: /category_id|status_id|personal_bias|business_value/}`

Comment: @Stevens we can take help of constraint,it depends at what level you have to go suppose i want to group by all available columns(or except some column) in my table then might be constraint approach will not suitable.

Comment: You can... If the logic is more complex then just create a constraint module. `... constraints: GroupConstraint`

Comment: @Stevens sure if logic is complex you can segregated as per need

Answer (score 2):

Try out this:

```
@ideas_grouped = @ideas.group_by { |i| i.send(:"#{@group}")} if (@group = params[:group])
```

Comment: if params[:group] is external data then watch out for malicious input (e.g. params[:group] == 'destroy')

Answer (score 1):

what about :

```
@group = params[:group] if !params[:group].blank?
@ideas_grouped = ideas_hash.fetch(@group)

def ideas_hash
  {
    'category_id'     => ideas_by_category_id,
    'status_id'       => ideas_by_status_id,
    'personal_bias'   => ideas_by_personal_bias
    'business_value'  => ideas_by_business_value
  }
end

def ideas_by_category_id
  @ideas.group_by { |i| i.category_id }
end

def ideas_by_status_id
  @ideas.group_by { |i| i.status_id }
end

def ideas_by_personal_bias
  @ideas.group_by { |i| i.personal_bias }
end

def ideas_by_business_value
  @ideas.group_by { |i| i.business_value }
end
```

I would also make ideas_hash and all of the others method private.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the last time I touched Ruby is too far back so I cannot give you an example. As far as I understand your problem you are doing a mapping (group -> accessor method) there. So either you use a map object or you build a mapping function using a lambda.